# Select movie with multiple genre

Tags: mysql

I have 3 database:

```
anime : id, name, year
genre : id, name
anime_genre : anime_id, genre_id
```

I want to get all movies with two or more specific genres. For example movie1 and movie2 drama and comedy. For example, I'm looking for a movie with genres of comedy and drama and I need to receive all movies all movies with both these genres.
I tried to do like this, but I need both genres:

```
 select a.* from anime a where a.id IN 
 (SELECT ag.anime_id from anime_genre ag join genre g on ag.genre_id 
 WHERE ag.genre_id in (1,4))
```

Database:
[image: Database]

Comment: *I want to get all movies with two or more specific genres.* Take `anime_genre`. Restrict its rows with genres in interest only. Group by movie. Calculate the amount of different genres per movie, select only movies where it is equal to the amount of genres in interest. Then join all another tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It whould be a greate thing to include a cereate schema script to make it easier to answer your question.

#### Creation Script:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  year INT
);

CREATE TABLE genre (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE movie_genre (
  movie_id INT,
  genre_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, genre_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_movie FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie (id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_genre FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genre (id)
);

INSERT INTO movie VALUES
  (1, "Movie 1", 1991),
  (2, "Movie 2", 1992),
  (3, "Movie 3", 2003),
  (4, "Movie 4", 2014)
;

INSERT INTO genre VALUES
  (1, "Genre 1"),
  (2, "Genre 2"),
  (3, "Genre 3")
;

INSERT INTO movie_genre VALUES
  (1, 1), (1, 3),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 1)
;
```

#### Using `GROUP_CONCAT`

There are some ways to do what you want.

In the following example you just need to change `HAVING` condition to include your genres. Note that genres in condition must be sorted.

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.name, 
    m.year, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(g.name ORDER BY g.name) as GENRES
FROM
  movie m
JOIN
  movie_genre mg ON mg.movie_id = m.id
JOIN
  genre g ON g.id = mg.genre_id
GROUP BY
  m.id, m.name, m.year
HAVING
  GROUP_CONCAT(g.name ORDER BY g.name) LIKE 'Genre 1%Genre 3'
;
```

The result:

```
id  name    year    GENRES
1   Movie 1 1991    Genre 1,Genre 3
4   Movie 4 2014    Genre 1,Genre 2,Genre 3
```

#### Using `COUNT`

Here is one other way, which allows to enter geners in any order, but requires to set condition on genre count:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.name, 
    m.year
FROM
  movie m
JOIN
  movie_genre mg ON mg.movie_id = m.id
JOIN
  genre g ON g.id = mg.genre_id
WHERE
  g.name IN ("Genre 1", "Genre 3")
GROUP BY
  m.id, m.name, m.year
HAVING
  COUNT(g.id) = 2
;
```

Here you should change `IN` set and `HAVING` count.

The result is quite the same:

```
id  name    year
1   Movie 1 1991
4   Movie 4 2014
```